# derivative of trace of (XAX) w.r.t X when X is symmetric?

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace

I wonder if there is any formula of $\frac{d tr(XAX)}{d X}$ when $X$ is symmetric?

---

I understand that when $X$ is not symmetric, we have $$\frac{d tr(XAX^T)}{dX} = XA^T+XA,$$
and when $X$ is symmetric, we have $$\frac{d tr(AX)}{dX} = A+A^T-A\circ I,$$
where $\circ$ means elementwise product.

However, I am not able to find $\frac{d tr(XAX)}{d X}$ when $X$ is given to be symmetric. Or any hint on the derivative of this formula is appreciated.

Comment: You title and question body are inconsistent: in the title you mention trace, but there is no trace anywhere in your formulas?

Comment: @user7530 Thank you!

Comment: This [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3667029) might be helpful. In particular, several of the answers and comments refer to a [paper by Panda](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.06491.pdf) which is worth reading.

Comment: If you've read the Panda paper, then you know that you can take the gradient for the non-symmetric $\big(X\ne X^T\big)$ case, $\big({\rm i.e.\;}G=XA^T+XA\big)\;$ and symmetrize it to obtain the gradient for the symmetric $\big(X=X^T\big)$ case: $\;G = \frac 12\big(XA^T+XA + AX+A^TX \big)\;$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For matrix derivatives I find it far easier to think about differentials. If we write $f(X) = \operatorname{tr}(XAX)$ and let $\delta X$ be an arbitrary variation of $X$, then
$$df(X)\delta X = \operatorname{tr}(\delta X A X + XA\delta X)$$
from the product rule and linearity of trace.
Then we can use the invariance of trace under cyclic permutations to write the above as
$$df(X)\delta X = \operatorname{tr}(A X \delta X + X A \delta X)$$
and finally since $\operatorname{tr}(AB) = A^T : B$, where $:$ is the Frobenius product,
$$df(X)\delta X = (XA^T + A^TX) : \delta X.$$
Now the notion of a "derivative" of a function with respect to a matrix does not have an entirely standard definition, but if we take it to mean "the matrix whose Frobenius product with $\delta X$ gives you the directional derivative in the $\delta X$ direction" (which I assume is the case from your examples in the OP) then we have our answer: the derivative of $f$ is
$$XA^T + A^TX.$$

**Important but subtle note**: this is the derivative of $\operatorname{tr}(XAX)$ at a symmetric matrix $X$. It is not the same as the derivative of $\operatorname{tr}(X^TAX)$ (even if $X$ is assumed symmetric), although the two functions have the same *directional derivative in symmetric directions.*

Comment: So it has the same solution with $\frac{dtr(XXA)}{dX}$, when $X$ is not  assumed symmetric in the derivation? The solution is $\frac{dtr(XXA)}{dX} = A^TX^T + X^TA^T$.

Comment: @tan trace is invariant under cyclic permutations, so yes.