# How to use barrier method for constraints like $X \succ 0$?

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, positive-definite, numerical-optimization

When reading about [interior-point methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior-point_method) in Stephen Boyd & Lieven Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook), a question arose about how to use barrier method for the constraint $X$ is **positive definite**, i.e., $X \succ 0$.

Intuitively, we can add logarithmic barrier function ${\log\det(X)}$ to the objective function, but when calculating the Newton step, we have to get the derivative of ${\log\det(X)}$ and the second derivative of ${(\log \det(X))^{-1}}$. It is easy to find that the derivative ${\log\det(X)}$ is $X^{-1}$, but it seems quite difficult to get the second derivative. So, how to deal with such a problem?

Comment: Off-topic, but you may find [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33414/339790) useful.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1447692/339790)

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/247043/339790)

Comment: [Also related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/38701/339790)