# Derivative of determinant, which is correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

I've seen two different results on the derivatives of determinants of matrices:

$$\frac{\partial |X|}{\partial X_{ij}}=X_{ij}.\tag1$$

$$\frac{\partial\det(X)}{\partial X}=|X|(X^{-1})^{T}.\tag2$$

These seem to imply different things. Which is right and why? Can't find it proven anywhere.

Comment: Maybe this can suggest a hint ?http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38701/how-to-calculate-the-gradient-of-log-det-matrix-inverse.

Comment: The first one is manifestly wrong, because implies $|X|=\frac{1}{2}X_{ij}^2+(\text{terms-not-depending-on-}X_{ij})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given, by Laplace Theorem, and for each choice of $i$
$$
|X|=\sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{i+j}X_{ij}M_{ij}
$$
where $M_{ij}$ is the cofactor of $X_{ij}$ and does not contain $X_{ij}$, we have
$$
\frac{\partial |X|}{\partial X_{ij}}=(-1)^{i+j}M_{ij}
$$
If the matrix is invertible, we have
$$
X^{-1}_{ij}=\frac{1}{|X|}(-1)^{i+j}M_{ji}
$$
and so
$$
\frac{\partial |X|}{\partial X_{ij}}=|X|X^{-1}_{ji}
$$

Comment: Cheers for this. I was just about clawing my way there. Name of the Laplace theorem is really useful. Gives a handle other than 'that thing you do to get det()'.