# How to calculate correctly the gradient of log det $\psi(x)$ matrix?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I have a function:
$$ \psi(t) = \frac{1}{2} \ln det\left(-\frac{\Omega(t)^{-1}}{2}\right) $$
where $\Omega(t)$ is a symmetric matrix semi-definite positive of size $k$. When I want to calculate the gradient, I have three different solutions, so I would like to know what mistakes I have made, what is the correct solution (for me **case(1)**)

To calculate the gradient $[\ln det(X)]$ where $X$ is a matrix, I used **[1]**, where $[\nabla \ln det(X)] = X^{-1}$

**Case (1):** Using the fact that $det(a\Sigma) = a^k det(\Sigma)$ where $a$ is a constant and $\Sigma$ a matrix of size $k \times k$, and **[1]**:
\begin{align}
\psi(t) &= \frac{1}{2} \left[ \ln \frac{1}{(-2)^k} - \ln det(\Omega(t)) \right]\\
\nabla_t \psi(t) &= - \frac{\Omega(t)^{-1}}{2}\\
\end{align}

**Case (2):** Using the fact that $det(A^{-1}) = det(A)^{-1}$, $\ln det(A)^{-1} = -\ln det(A) $ and **[1]**:
\begin{align}
\psi(t) &= -\frac{1}{2} \ln det(-2\Omega(t))\\
\nabla_t \psi(t) &= \frac{\Omega(t)^{-1}}{4}\\
\end{align}

**Case(3):** Using the fact that $\Xi(t) = (-2\Omega(t))^{-1}$ and **[1]**:
\begin{align}
\psi(t) &= \frac{1}{2} \ln det(\Xi(t))\\
\nabla_t \psi(t) &= \frac{1}{2} \Xi(t)^{-1} = -\Omega(t) \\
\end{align}

Thanks in advance for your help

[1] [How to calculate the gradient of log det matrix inverse?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38701/how-to-calculate-the-gradient-of-log-det-matrix-inverse) or [How to calculate the gradient of log det matrix inverse?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38701/how-to-calculate-the-gradient-of-log-det-matrix-inverse?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: All of your cases attempt to calculate $\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial\Omega}$ but your question (and nabla notation) suggest that you actually wanted to calculate $$\nabla_t\phi=\frac{d\psi}{dt} = -\tfrac{1}{2}{\rm Tr}\big(\Omega^{-1}\tfrac{\partial\Omega}{\partial t}\big)$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this is by a change of variables.

You already know that for symmetric matrices

$$d \operatorname{logdet}(X) = X^{-1} : dX$$

Let $$ U = -\frac{1}{2}\Omega^{-1}; \quad U^{-1}=-2\Omega$$

then
$$ dU = \frac{1}{2}{\Omega^{-1} d\Omega \Omega^{-1}} $$

We have that

$$
\eqalign{
\phi &= \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{logdet}U \\
d\phi &= \frac{1}{2}U^{-1} : dU \\
&=-\Omega : \frac{1}{2}\Omega^{-1}d\Omega\Omega^{-1} \\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\Omega^{-1} : d\Omega
}$$

Thus 
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \Omega}= -\frac{1}{2}\Omega^{-1}$$