# How can I calculate $\frac{\partial \log |\Sigma|}{\partial \rho }$ where $\Sigma=(1-\rho)I+\rho\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^\top$?

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I need to calculate the $\dfrac{\partial \log |\Sigma|}{\partial \rho }$ when $\Sigma = (1-\rho) I + \rho \mathbf{1} \mathbf{1}^\top$ and $\Sigma$ has dimension $p \times p$.

I try to use the formula presented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38701/how-to-calculate-the-gradient-of-log-det-matrix-inverse) and [here](https://blog.as.uky.edu/sta707/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/matrix-derivatives.pdf) but the result is not right.

Comment: Without trying anything fancy,  you can simply calculate $|\Sigma|$ and proceed as usual.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative wrt $\rho$ is $\operatorname{trace}((-I+11^T){\Sigma}^{-1})$.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain loup blanc's result
$$\eqalign{
\Sigma &= I + \rho\,({\tt\large 11}^T-I) \\
d\Sigma &= ({\tt\large 11}^T-I)\,d\rho \\
\beta &= \det(\Sigma) \\
d\beta &= \beta\,\Sigma^{-1} \\
\lambda &= \log(\beta) \\
d\lambda &= \frac{d\beta}{\beta} \\
 &= \Sigma^{-1}:d\Sigma \\ 
 &= \Sigma^{-1}:({\tt\large 11}^T-I)\,d\rho \\
\frac{d\lambda}{d\rho} &= \Sigma^{-1}:({\tt\large 11}^T-I) \\
}$$
where a colon is used as a convenient product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$\eqalign{A:B = {\rm tr}(A^TB)}$$
and [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) is used to differentiate $\beta$.