# Computing the smoothness of GDA with respect to covariance matrix

Tags: calculus, matrix-calculus, maximum-likelihood

I'm trying to compute the beta-smoothness of the log-likelihood for Gaussian Discriminant Analysis, with respect to the covariance matrix $\Sigma$.

We have
$$
\ell(\phi, \boldsymbol \mu_0, \boldsymbol \mu_1, \boldsymbol \Sigma) = \sum_{i=1}^m \left( y^{(i)} \log \phi + (1 - y^{(i)}) \log (1 - \phi) -\frac{1}{2} \log |\boldsymbol \Sigma|+ C + (\textbf{x}^{(i)}-\boldsymbol \mu)^T \boldsymbol \Sigma^{-1} (\textbf{x}^{(i)} - \boldsymbol \mu) \right)
$$

I used [this StackExchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38701/how-to-calculate-the-gradient-of-log-det-matrix-inverse/38704#38704) to deduce that $\nabla_A \log \lvert A \rvert = (A^{-1})^T$, and using that and the trace trick, I got the gradient as

$$
\nabla_\Sigma \ell = -\frac{m}{2}(\Sigma^{-1})^T + \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{i=1}^m \mathrm{tr } (x^{(i)} - \boldsymbol \mu)(x^{(i)} - \boldsymbol \mu)^T (\Sigma^{-1})^2
$$

Finally, I got the second gradient as

$$
\nabla_\Sigma^2 \ell = -\frac{m}{2}\left( (\Sigma^{-1})^2 \right)^T - \sum\limits_{i=1}^m \mathrm{tr } (x^{(i)}-\boldsymbol \mu)(x^{(i)}-\boldsymbol \mu)^T (\Sigma^{-1})^3
$$

And I can apply a norm and a max operator on both sides to get the beta-smoothness expression. For both of these equations, I used $d(X^{-1}) = X^{-1}dX X^{-1}$, but I'm not sure if that means $\nabla_X X^{-1} = (X^{-1})^2$ (which I've used for the above two). Are my derivations correct, and if so, what's the correct way to use this identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\l{\lambda} \def\S{\Sigma} \def\Si{\S^{-1}}
\def\h{\frac 12}
\def\d{{\large\delta}}
\def\A{{\cal A}} \def\H{{\cal H}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\vecc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial} \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Let $w=\LR{x-\mu}$ and truncate terms which don't depend on $\S$.

This leaves the function
$$\eqalign{
\l &= ww^T:\Si - \h\log\det(\S) \\
}$$
where $(:)$ denotes the Frobenius product, which is a concise
notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\:norm} \} \\
}$$
Calculate the differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
d\l &= ww^T:\CLR{d\Si} - \h\Si:d\S \\
 &= ww^T:\CLR{-\Si d\S\,\Si} - \h\Si:d\S \\
 &= -\LR{\Si ww^T\Si + \h\Si}:d\S \\
\grad{\l}{\S} &= -\Si\BR{ww^T + \h\S}\Si \;\doteq\; G \\
\\
}$$
Then calculate the differential and gradient of $G$
$$\eqalign{
dG &= -d\Si\BR{ww^T + \h\S}\Si
   - \Si\BR{\h\:d\S}\Si 
   - \Si\BR{ww^T + \h\S}d\Si \\
 &= \Si\,d\S\,G - \h\Si\,d\S\:\Si + G\,d\S\,\Si  \\
 &= \LR{\Si\A G - \h\Si\A\Si + G\A \Si}:d\S  \\
\grad{G}{\S} &= {\Si\A G - \h\Si\A\Si + G\A \Si} \;\doteq\; \H \\
}$$
where $\H$ is the Hessian and $\A$ is the fourth-order identity tensor
$$\eqalign{
\S &= \A:\S &\;=\; \S:\A \\
\A &= \grad{\S}{\S} &\implies\quad
 \A_{ijkl} = \grad{\S_{ij}}{\S_{kl}}  = \d_{ik}\,\d_{jl} \\
}$$
In this derivation, the fact that $\{\S,G\}$ are symmetric matrices was used in several steps.

An alternative to using tensors is to [vectorize](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products)
the matrices using Kronecker products
$$\eqalign{
{dG} &= \Si\,d\S\,G - \h\Si\,d\S\:\Si + G\,d\S\,\Si  \\
\vecc{dG}
 &= \LR{{G\otimes\Si}-\h\,{\Si\otimes\Si}+{\Si\otimes G}}\vecc{d\S} \\
\grad{\vecc G}{\vecc\S}
 &= {G\otimes\Si}-\h\,{\Si\otimes\Si}+{\Si\otimes G} \\
}$$